# Upgrading with quarkus update --stream=3.0 from 2.16.7.Final to 3.0.2.Final fails

Tags: quarkus

If I manually fix the jakarta packages and upgrade quarkus version in pom the project compiles and runs fine.

But if I use the "quarkus update --stream=3.0" CLI command (or the mvnw version) it fails that a class is missing, example attached.

Looking at external dependencies jackson-annotations-2.14.2.jar version is visible, so that seems OK.

```
 Number of foreign imports: 1
[INFO] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>com.ech:console-services:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:169)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:298)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:53)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:152)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:76)
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView
[INFO]     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.<clinit> (JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:37)
[INFO]     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<clinit> (ObjectMapper.java:375)
[INFO]     at org.openrewrite.config.YamlResourceLoader.<init> (YamlResourceLoader.java:140)
[INFO]     at org.openrewrite.config.ClasspathScanningLoader.lambda$scanYaml$0 (ClasspathScanningLoader.java:106)
[INFO]     at io.github.classgraph.ResourceList.forEachInputStreamIgnoringIOException (ResourceList.java:527)
[INFO]     at org.openrewrite.config.ClasspathScanningLoader.scanYaml (ClasspathScanningLoader.java:105)
[INFO]     at org.openrewrite.config.ClasspathScanningLoader.<init> (ClasspathScanningLoader.java:56)
[INFO]     at org.openrewrite.config.Environment$Builder.scanRuntimeClasspath (Environment.java:193)
[INFO]     at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteMojo.environment (AbstractRewriteMojo.java:115)
[INFO]     at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteMojo.listResults (AbstractRewriteMojo.java:207)
[INFO]     at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteRunMojo.execute (AbstractRewriteRunMojo.java:54)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:298)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:53)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:152)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:76)
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
[INFO]     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.<clinit> (JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:37)
[INFO]     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<clinit> (ObjectMapper.java:375)
[INFO]     at org.openrewrite.config.YamlResourceLoader.<init> (YamlResourceLoader.java:140)
[INFO]     at org.openrewrite.config.ClasspathScanningLoader.lambda$scanYaml$0 (ClasspathScanningLoader.java:106)
[INFO]     at io.github.classgraph.ResourceList.forEachInputStreamIgnoringIOException (ResourceList.java:527)
[INFO]     at org.openrewrite.config.ClasspathScanningLoader.scanYaml (ClasspathScanningLoader.java:105)
[INFO]     at org.openrewrite.config.ClasspathScanningLoader.<init> (ClasspathScanningLoader.java:56)
[INFO]     at org.openrewrite.config.Environment$Builder.scanRuntimeClasspath (Environment.java:193)
[INFO]     at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteMojo.environment (AbstractRewriteMojo.java:115)
[INFO]     at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteMojo.listResults (AbstractRewriteMojo.java:207)
[INFO]     at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteRunMojo.execute (AbstractRewriteRunMojo.java:54)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:298)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:53)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:152)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:76)
[INFO] [ERROR]
[INFO] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[INFO] [ERROR]
[INFO] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[INFO] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.567 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-10T11:47:40+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.0.2.Final:update (default-cli) on project webconsole-backend-services: Failed to resolve the available updates: Error while running the project update script: Error while executing command to udpate the project: The command to update the project exited with an error: 1 -> [Help 1]
```

Any idea why the auto update fails in this case?

Comment: are you able to make a reproducer so we can investigate?